# Dropdown menu breaking while loading

Tags: php, javascript, html

Please tell me the solution why my dropdown menu is breaking while loading? [Click Here](http://www.fedri.com/bh/) for the link.

Full Details:

```
    When the website is loading, its showing all the sub menus present inside and after its loads completly its showing correctly. At the start it should be strong and should not show inside present sub menu...
```

It has the below java codes.

```
<link href="css/dcmegamenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.dcmegamenu.1.3.3.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($){
    $('#mega-menu-7').dcMegaMenu({
        rowItems: '3',
        speed: 'fast',
        effect: 'slide'
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: In what way is it breaking?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by breaking? What are you expecting and what is happening?

Comment: I have posted the discription.. please check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this once:

```
$(function() {

    // Handler for .ready() called.
    $('#mega-menu-7').dcMegaMenu({
        rowItems: '3',
        speed: 'fast',
        effect: 'slide'
    });

});​
```

Answer (score 3):

you are not including the jQuery link

```
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js'></script>
```

try this by removing `$` in the ready function

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
   // put all your jQuery goodness in here.
   });
```

this is [jQuery code](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aIntroducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29) . so u must add jQuery source .

Comment: Hi, is it compulsory. Without that also I found my problem solve by refering below answer. Do I put this script also ?? Please let me know

Comment: you mean <script>... ? yes u must to let jquery work if you have jquery code.in your code you are using jquery code , so u must include jquery library

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
I was having this script before, I removed it becaasue its making problem to some other script in my website. I hope your script will not make any problem with other codes.

Comment: you had problem maybe because it conflict between your codes , and maybe you are using joomla or wordpress so they use `mootools` also , to remove the conflict , use `[NOCONFLICT](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)`

Comment: nice that it helps you but since you are accepting the other answer i appreciate it also . good luck with the rest.